# Unable to connect to mosquitto broker server in mqtt-react

Tags: reactjs, mqtt, mosquitto

I am using a mosquitto for my broker server, when I use mqtt-react and put my internet's local ip address I get this error in the console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.XXX.X.X:1883/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

and in my terminal where mosquitto is opened, it says this

```
Client <unknown> disconnected due to protocol error.
```

Any ideas appreciated

Comment: Edit the question to include your mosquitto.conf so we can see if you have configured a Websocket Listener (port 1883 is normally Native MQTT not MQTT over Websockets)

Comment: @hardillb my mosquitto.conf is still all in comments

Answer (score 2):

MQTT react is trying to use MQTT over Websockets to connect to the broker, this is because it is based in a web browser so the sandbox will only allow HTTP or Websocket connections

By default Mosquitto only starts one listener (on port 1883) which only supports MQTT over TCP. If you want to connect with MQTT over Websockets you will need to add a new listener on a new port. To do this add the following to your `mosquitto.conf` file:

```
listener 8083
protocol websockets
```

You will need to update the URL in your code for the broker to be as follows:

```
ws://192.XXX.X.X:8083
```

Comment: After I do that, I get this error ```Unable to start any listening sockets, exiting.```

Comment: Edit the question to show your mosquitto.conf and the full log output when it starts

Comment: Ok, so I was able to run the server with your solution after I uncomment the port 1883 line, are both port and listeners needed at the same time? and are both port and listeners must be at a different number?

Comment: You can not have multiple listeners on the same port. As to if you need both I can't answer that as I don't know what else is using MQTT in your system.